# How do you increment the value of a variable based on a substring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script where I validate a phone number without too much regex in my scripts. So far I have:

```
var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
var num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
var delim = ["(" , ")" , "-" , "."];
var incr = 0;
var status = 0;

if (document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring() = num) {
    incr++;
    return;
}

if (incr < 10) {
    var statustext=1;
    alert("Phone data is missing.");
}

if (document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != num || document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != delim) {
    (status var statustext=1;
    alert("Phone data is incorrect.");)
}

if (statustext == 0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

but it's not working. I'm trying to increment my incr everytime there is a number so if incr < 10, i get a message that there aren't enough numbers. Anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: It looks like a partial code... can you add a JsFiddle or SO snippet that reproduces your issue? it will be much easier to help you ...

Comment: The code as posted would through runtime errors.

Comment: There are syntax and semantic errors ...  syntax: `substring[0,4,8]` (property or array index access with multiple values on function), semantic: `if(...substring()=num)` (assignment is wrong here)

Comment: `(status var statustext=1;` is also invalid for multiple reasons.

Comment: You're right it is only partial code. This would run when a person clicks a submit button. I only included this portion because everything thing stops running once I changed the script to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your below if condition :

```
if (document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != num || document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != delim) {
    (status var statustext=1;
    alert("Phone data is incorrect.");)
}
```

1. Declare your statustext set globally. Not inside the if condition.
2. status set to 1 directly.

change your logic as below

```
var statustext = 0;
if (document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != num || document.PizzaForm.phone.value.substring[0,4,8] != delim) {
    status = 1;
    statustext = 1;
    alert("Phone data is incorrect.");)
}
```